# How to create a new column based on previous row with DAX - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi on powerBI  I have something like this

[image]

Desire result is this to create another column **'is_repeat from previous row'**

where it is 'True' when the current row is repeat the top row

[image]

I tried to use 'EARLIER' function to compare current row to previous but EARLIER grey out my 'index' column - not sure why

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR ThisIndex = Table1[INDEX]
VAR PreviousIndex = ThisIndex - 1
VAR ThisCode = Table1[code]
VAR PreviousCode =
    LOOKUPVALUE( Table1[code], Table1[INDEX], PreviousIndex )
RETURN
    ThisCode = PreviousCode
```

Comment: hope to use the [OFFSET function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3QY0DWts8w) soon

Comment: @UmutK Yes, good point, that will be a nice addition.